# Math notation for applying formula over each value in a subset

Tags: discrete-mathematics, notation, education

I am not very related to mathematical notation, and I have looked for examples to solve my doubt but I haven't found anything convincing so far.

For a data mining project, I'm trying to write, in mathematical notation, the formula I used to calculate a factor which helps me on handling outliers in a data vector/column/set. What I'm trying to represent is the following:

**"Having a set named *P1***

***F* is a new set consisting of:**

**each element *p* of *P1*, starting at the second element, applying [this formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HM9Mp.png)"**

For clarifying the sentence above I made this example on Python:

I have this starting dataset, consisting only of a vector/column/set named *P1*:

[Input dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qkjxt.png)

Then I applied the formula:

```
import math
# This is the formula I want to translate to math notation
# Notice that I'm iterating over a subset of P1 which is P1 statring in its second element

F = [math.log(p/min(P1)) for p in P1[1:]]
```

Appending *F* to the original dataframe we got this new dataframe:

[Desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0bZz.png)

This is what I have written so far for representing the construction of set *F*:

[image]

I have a feeling that there is something wrong in my math notation sentence(specifically because the sentence does not specify that the *p* elements belong to *P1*).

• If I don't have anything wrong: I would appreciate you to tell me.

• If I do have something wrong: can some mathematician hero help me correct my syntax?

Greetings

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Are the data vectors you talk about, vectors in the mathematical sense? Are your readers familiar with math notations generally associated with vectors? If so, you could use $F = \sum_{k=2}^p {\rm formula}(p_k) \cdot {\bf e_{k-1}}$. Or else, do you have any notation for accessing an element out of your data vector? (e.g., in computer science, there is v[i]). Then you could say $F[i-2] = {\rm formula}(p_i), \ i = \overline{2, n}$ assuming F[0] is the first element.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your responses. What I mean with vector is a 'set', a vector of a matrix.
F is not a sum, it is a set composed by each p element processed by the formula.

Comment: You don't need the "for all" symbol.  This is implied in set notatiion.  Set notation is $\{value | condition\}$ so you would want $F= \{\ln\frac p{\min P_1}| p\in \{p_2,....,p_2\}\}$.  Or $F=\{\ln\frac p{\min P_1}| p\in P_1 \setminus\{p_1\}\}$ or  $F=\{\ln\frac p{\min P_1}| p\in P_1; p\ne p_1\}$.

Comment: The real issue is that sets are not ordered and there is no "action" in a set about doing terms one after another  A set just has all values at once.

Comment: Thank you @fleablood. 
If the set notation you mention involves the entire P1 column, I guess I could use something like: $$F= \{\ln\frac{p_i}{\min P1}|p_i∈P1;p_i≠p_1\}$$. Just a question: are indexes redundant here or it's ok to indicate them? PD: thanks to JoséCarlosSantos for introducing MathJax to me :)